# AS3/Flash Performance of Spritesheets/Starling

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, sprite-sheet, starling-framework

I am currently trying to optimize a AS3/Flash web (browser) app (FP11+).  It's a full browser window flash app that loads the environment/background graphics remotely via (Greensock's) SWFLoader and adds them as bitmaps (the download time isn't causing an issue).  Other minor graphics like buttons, processing/loading animations, windows and UI elements are drawn using AS3 graphics api.

I'm running into FPS issues (target is 40) when loading in additional swfs for display inside the flash app (FPS varies greatly when the loaded SWFs are animating and drops to zero).  Avg MB usage is between 50-100MB (as reported by FlashProfiler).

My question is: Will implementing the use of a local spritesheet for the remotely loaded graphics and/or the drawn graphics would result in a significant performance boost?

Secondly, since Starling utilizes the GPU for processing and animation, would converting the app to use Starling result in a significant performance boost?

Or, am I stuck focusing on maximizing the performance of loops, lists/vectors and data usage?  Regarding such, I've read mixed opinions on using arrays/lists vs. vectors and also foreach vs. collection-specific functions (filter,map, etc). Any experience on direct comparison of those techniques would be helpful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide link for us to see the application? Other than that I have no experience using sprite sheets in Flash Player applications (I am assuming you refer to images where individual frames are layed out beside each other within one single image, reducing animation to moving a "window" onto each such frame graphics). A GPU-driven framework like Starling is able to process thousands of objects without breaking a sweat, so that could help. You *should* pay attention to your loops and data usage patterns first though - basically, profile first and re-factor it accoringly.

Comment: @amn: Yes, what you described is what I consider a spritesheet as well.  They're heavily used in game dev. I don't think the link will help describe it anymore than I already have, but for the next 24-48hrs, this link will be active: [link](http://awsm.playvue.com).  See edited for add'l request re loops, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Starling will help considerably when you have a lot of bitmap assets to display on a computer or device with a GPU to give acceleration. If you use Starling, you will get better performance by placing the various images in a sprite sheet to cut down on the number of draw calls the GPU has to perform.

So, lots of images plus significant numbers of rotations or scaling will make good use of a GPU's strengths. If you are continually redrawing things like vector graphics or other canvas type operations, Starling probably won't help much. Nor will it help on computers with unsupported GPUs.

After you make the bitmap vs. render decision, any optimization of actual AS3 code should be done with a profiler.